# Simple Keras neural network isn't learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, mnist

I'm trying to replicate some of the examples from [Neural Networks and Deep Learning](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/index.html) with Keras, but I'm having problems training a network based on the architecture from chapter 1. The aim is to classify written digits from the MNIST dataset. 
The architecture:

- 784 inputs (one for each of the 28 * 28 pixels in MNIST images)
- a hidden layer of 30 neurons
- an output layer of 10 neurons
- Weights and biases are initialized from a Gaussian distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 1.
- The loss/cost function is mean squared error.
- The optimizer is stochastic gradient descent.

Hyper-parameters:

- learning rate = 3.0
- batch size = 10
- epochs = 30

My code:

```python
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.initializers import RandomNormal


# import data
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows * img_cols)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows * img_cols)
input_shape = (img_rows * img_cols,)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
num_classes = 10
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
print('y_train shape:', y_train.shape)

# Construct model
# 784 * 30 * 10
# Normal distribution for weights/biases
# Stochastic Gradient Descent optimizer
# Mean squared error loss (cost function)
model = Sequential()
layer1 = Dense(30,
               input_shape=input_shape,
               kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(stddev=1),
               bias_initializer=RandomNormal(stddev=1))
model.add(layer1)
layer2 = Dense(10,
               kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(stddev=1),
               bias_initializer=RandomNormal(stddev=1))
model.add(layer2)
print('Layer 1 input shape: ', layer1.input_shape)
print('Layer 1 output shape: ', layer1.output_shape)
print('Layer 2 input shape: ', layer2.input_shape)
print('Layer 2 output shape: ', layer2.output_shape)

model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=3.0),
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train 
model.fit(x_train,
          y_train,
          batch_size=10,
          epochs=30,
          verbose=2)

# Run on test data and output results
result = model.evaluate(x_test,
                        y_test,
                        verbose=1)
print('Test loss: ', result[0])
print('Test accuracy: ', result[1])
```

Output (Using Python 3.6 and the TensorFlow backend):

```python
Using TensorFlow backend.
x_train shape: (60000, 784)
60000 train samples
10000 test samples
y_train shape: (60000, 10)
Layer 1 input shape:  (None, 784)
Layer 1 output shape:  (None, 30)
Layer 2 input shape:  (None, 30)
Layer 2 output shape:  (None, 10)
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 30)                23550     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                310       
=================================================================
Total params: 23,860
Trainable params: 23,860
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/30
 - 7s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0987
Epoch 2/30
 - 7s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0987
```

(repeated for all 30 epochs)

```python
Epoch 30/30
 - 6s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0987
10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 22us/step
Test loss:  nan
Test accuracy:  0.098
```

As you can see, the network isn't learning at all, and I'm not sure why. The shapes look all right as far as I can tell. What am I doing that's preventing the network from learning?

(Incidentally, I know that cross-entropy loss and a softmax output layer would be better; however, from the linked book, they don't appear to be necessary. The book's manually implemented network in chapter 1 learns successfully; I'm trying to replicate that before moving on.)

Comment: why do you use mse ? you have a classification problem here

Comment: @serafeim As I said in the last paragraph, I'm trying to replicate the manually implemented network from the linked book, which uses mean squared error (though the book calls it the quadratic cost function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the activations of each layer. So for each layer. should be something like this:

```python
layer2 = Dense(10,
           activation='sigmoid',
           kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(stddev=1),
           bias_initializer=RandomNormal(stddev=1))
```

notice I specified the activation parameter here. Also for the last layer, you should use `activation="softmax"` since you have multiple categories.

Another thing to consider, is that classification (as opposed to regression) would work best with an entropy loss. So you might want to change the loss value in `model.compile` to `loss='categorical_crossentropy'`. However, this is not necessary, and you will still get a result using a `mean_square_error` loss.

If you still get `nan` value for the loss, you can try to change learning rate for `SGD`.

I got test accurracy of `0.9425` using the script you show by only changing the activations of the first layer to `sigmoid` and second layer to `softmax`.

Comment: Not specifying the activations was indeed the problem; with both layers set to `sigmoid`, I get a test accuracy of `0.9468`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Choosing MSE as a loss function in a classification problem is indeed odd, and I am not sure the introductory nature of the exercise is a good justification, as claimed in the linked book chapter. Nevertheless:

1. Your learning rate `lr`, 3.0, is *huge*; try something at least 0.1, or even lower.
2. As is, your layers lack completely any activation function; try adding `activation='sigmoid'` at all layers (since you explicitly want to avoid `softmax`, even in the final layer).
3. The `stddev=1` value you use in your initializers is again *huge*; try something in the range of 0.05 ([default value](https://keras.io/initializers/#randomnormal)). Also, the [standard practice](https://keras.io/initializers/) is to initialize the *biases* to zeros.

It would be probably better to start with the [Keras MNIST MLP example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py), and adapt it to your learning needs (regarding number of layers, activation functions etc).

Comment: The lack of activation functions was the problem. That said, if the hyper-parameters are so far off from what's typical, I'm rethinking using this book!

Comment: @DylanSp well, indeed MNIST has a reputation that... it will converge to a decent solution, whatever hyperparameters you may use... ;)

Comment: Is there a fundamental theoretical reason for that? Is it just that MNIST is a relatively simple problem?

Comment: @DylanSp Deep learning is still notoriously poor in theory, and driven mainly by empirical results (i.e. "here's something that works, although we don't know exactly why it works...")

Comment: I agree with @desertnaut on learning rate. Having is set to `3` is a huge mistake in my opinion. Have you taken this value from the book provided? Because if yes - then there is something seriously wrong with it.